# why .tiff format image not showing in Android WebView?

Tags: android, image, android-webview, tiff

I can't show .tiff file in Android `WebView`. Is Android `WebView` supports .tiff file format?

If yes, How to show .tiff file in Android `WebView`? Give me any solution regarding this.

Comment: I don't think TIFFs are natively supported. There's apps you can use to view them though.

Comment: @dmon, Actually I have loaded my client URL in my `WebView`. In that URL have .tiff image file. But .tiff image not showing in Android `WebView`.

Comment: yes, that would be, as dmon indicated, because they are probably not supported.

Comment: Try viewing your URL in the stock Browser app. If you cannot see the TIFF file there, then `WebView` does not support TIFF, since the Browser app uses `WebView` for its content rendering.

Comment: Android not support tiff file format. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#image-formats